# Relative system path to miktex and pandoc - Shiny Application packaged as Windows desktop app

Tags: r, path, shiny, pandoc, miktex

I have packaged a Shiny application as a Windows desktop App by following the following tutorial: http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/

In my Shiny application I provide the user to generate a PDF Report using pandoc and MikTex. 
In order for this to work in my Desktop application, I have added the following code in my runShinyApp.R script.

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("C:/Users/WoBa/Documents/dist/pandoc",sep=";",
"C:/Users/WoBa/Documents/dist/miktex/miktex/bin/"))
```

Although this works correctly, I would like this path to be relative so the application can be distributed to other users without them having to change the path.

I've tried the following - but this didn't work:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("./pandoc",sep=";",
"./miktex/miktex/bin/"))
```

**Folder structure is the following:**

```
dist/
 + GoogleChromePortable
 + miktex
 + pandoc
 + R-Portable
 + runShinyApp.R
 + run.bat
```

Anybody maybe nows how to make this path relative? (on Windows) It would help me a lot!

Comment: You could try `Sys.which("pdflatex")` but I'm unsure exactly how it will interact with the desktop app setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to provide a relative path with the following code in my runShinyApp.R script:

```
miktex = file.path(getwd(), 'miktex/miktex/bin/')
pandoc = file.path(getwd(), 'pandoc')

Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(pandoc, sep=";", miktex))
```

Just providing the answer as this could be useful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a similar application using the same tutorial.
I have added the following to my runShinyApp.R-script based on a solution provided ny [Yihui Xie](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-markdown-pdf-generator-in-portable-version/7102), jst before the runApp command.

```
pandoc <- paste(getwd(), "pandoc-2.4", sep = "/")
TinyTex <- paste(getwd(), "TinyTeX/bin/win32", sep = "/")

add_path = function(path) {
  s = .Platform$path.sep
  paths = c(path, unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv('PATH'), s)))
  Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(paths, collapse = s))
}

add_path(pandoc)
add_path(TinyTex)
```